# A small SQL task with aggregate functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get count of C_ST's with '0' for each Abonent, but don't know how.
Tried to find solutions, but nothing works..

The Structure of Database:

[image: The Structure of Database]

**QRY_TYPE** (`ID` – unique identifier of type, `С_NAME` – name of type, `C_AB_REF` – link to the abonent, who processes these types of messages).

**ST_ABONENTS** (`ID` – unique identifier, `С_NAME` – name)

**QRY_QUEUE** (`ID` – unique identifier, `С_IN_TIME` – date and time of writing msg into table, `C_EXEC_TIME` – date and time of the msg processing, `C_ST` – processing status (null - didn't, 1 – successfull, 0 – error with processing), `C_QRY_TYPE` – link for the query type).

Thats one of my tries, its still doesnt work

```
SELECT ST_ABONENTS.C_NAME AS "ABONENTNAME",COUNT(QRY_QUEUE.C_ST) AS "CNT" 
FROM ST_ABONENTS, QRY_QUEUE 
WHERE QRY_QUEUE.C_ST=0 
GROUP BY ST_ABONENTS.C_NAME 
HAVING COUNT(QRY_QUEUE.C_ST)>0;
```

Result should looks like this

[image: Result]

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? Don't tag products not involved. (And one of those two has a bit odd group by behavior...)

Comment: oracle, already found solution, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would return each abonents count with `c_st = 0`

```
select a.c_name as abonentname, count(*) as cnt
from st_abonents a
inner join qry_type qt on a.id = qt.c_ab_ref
inner join qry_queue qq on qt.id = qq.c_qry_type
where qq.c_st = 0
group by a.c_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the joining conditions that relate the tables.

```
SELECT a.c_name AS ABONENTNAME, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM ST_ABONENTS AS a
JOIN QRY_TYPE AS t ON a.ID = t.C_AB_REF
JOIN QRY_QUEUE AS q ON q.C_QRY_TYPE = t.ID
WHERE q.C_ST = 0
GROUP BY ABONENTNAME
```